# Javascript page refresh/unload event

Tags: javascript

I need to do an animation when the page refreshes/unloads. I tried  `<body onunload="myFunction()">`  but it does not seem to be working. What should I do?

Comment: shouldnt it be `onbeforeunload `

Comment: your code isn't guaranteed to run with the unload events.

Comment: @johnSmith I dont think so: [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's no longer possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call a function before `refresh`, you can try the following:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
     myFunction();
});
```

Comment: I want it to fire an event on refresh, not after the refreshed page is loaded. Like an exit animation.

Comment: @kahveciderin you have to do it beforeunload because otherwise the site will be shut before it displays anything

Comment: @kahveciderin please let me know if this did not solve your problem. If it did, please mark the answer as the solution to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
  console.log('hello world');
});
```

Comment: I want it to fire after the page is unloaded, not loaded.

Comment: i modify my answer, try this